# how to call function inside trigger

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I am trying to create a function using Oracle PL/SQL. This function will be called inside a trigger. When I compile the trigger no error found, but when insert on table krs showing

```
ORA-04091: table TIKET_BUS.KRS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "TIKET_BUS.GET_BIAYA_SEMESTER", line 4
ORA-06512: at "TIKET_BUS.GET_BIAYA_SEMESTER", line 17
ORA-06512: at "TIKET_BUS.TAGIH", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'TIKET_BUS.TAGIH'
```

Any clues what I am missing?

function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION GET_BIAYA_SEMESTER
(NO_INDUK CHAR) RETURN NUMBER IS
CURSOR C_IPK IS
SELECT
k.SKS, n.kd_semester
FROM
MATA_KULIAH k, krs n
WHERE 
k.KD_MK = n.kd_mk and n.nim = NO_INDUK;
BARIS C_IPK%ROWTYPE;
S MAHASISWA.NAMA%TYPE;
TOTAL_BIAYA NUMBER := 0;
X NUMBER;
SKS NUMBER;
BIAYA NUMBER;
BEGIN
OPEN C_IPK;
LOOP
FETCH C_IPK INTO BARIS;
EXIT WHEN C_IPK%NOTFOUND;
X := BIAYA_MAKUL(BARIS.SKS);
TOTAL_BIAYA  := total_BIAYA + X;
END LOOP;
BIAYA := TOTAL_BIAYA;
CLOSE C_IPK;
RETURN BIAYA;
END;
```

trigger:

```
create or replace trigger tagih
after insert on krs
for each row
declare
x number;
begin
x := get_biaya_semester(:new.nim);
update tagihan set bayar = (x) where nim = :new.nim;
end;
```

Comment: Please study this link: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5432/what-are-the-causes-and-solutions-for-mutating-table-errors

Answer (score 0):

Code invoked from a row trigger cannot access the table on which the trigger is defined. Here the trigger is defined on table `KRS`, so no code in the trigger or in anything called by the trigger can access table `KRS`. In this case your function `GET_BIAYA_SEMESTER` access table `KRS`.

The easiest thing I can for you to do is to include the call to `GET_BIAYA_SEMESTER` in the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement, something like

```
UPDATE KRS
  SET SOME_FIELD = 123,
      SOME_OTHER_FIELD = 456,
      NIM = NIM_VALUE,
      BAYAR = GET_BIAYA_SEMESTER(NIM_VALUE);
```

This eliminates the need to call the function from the trigger.

Best of luck.